# Ajax type GET with data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Having trouble getting success from this...

```
<!-- Ajax -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.clickup').click(function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "actions.php",
    data: "action=10&moveMe=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['chkID'] ?>&startPos=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['orderID'] ?>&parentCategory=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['categoryID'] ?>&chklistID=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['chklistID'] ?>"
    success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
}
});
</script>
```

Normally, when I would just want the page to reload, I would set the `href` to:

```
actions.php?action=10&moveMe=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['chkID'] ?>&startPos=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['orderID'] ?>&parentCategory=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['categoryID'] ?>&chklistID=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['chklistID'] ?>
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am not getting my success alert.

Comment: What status code is the server returning when you fetch that URL - if it's not a 2xx code then chances are the success method will not be called.

Comment: any errors you get in the firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem could be that you have not wrapped your code in a jQuery load function, such as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('a.clickup').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = "action=10&moveMe=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['chkID'] ?>&startPos=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['orderID'] ?>&parentCategory=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['categoryID'] ?>&chklistID=<?php echo $row_rsChkOptions['chklistID'] ?>";
        $.get("actions.php", data, function (data) {
            alert('success');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This reason I suggest this is that trying to apply a click function handler on a DOM element when the DOM element hasn't fully loaded by the browser can cause problems.  Wrapping your code in a jQuery load function such as this will take care of that problem if that is indeed what is happening.  I also took the liberty of rewriting your $.ajax function call to make it a little easier on the eyes.  But that is purely subjective!!

Comment: this rewrite got me a success. Now I just need to fix up my actions.php page to handle things properly.... Thanks!